# Registering a COM dll on another machine

Tags: c#, com, interop, registry

I have written a class library of which a UserControl is ComVisible.

When I register this using Visual Studio (check the "Register for Com interop" box and build), it is registered and works well. Now I would like to register on another machine. How do I do this?

I have tried using this (and every possible combination of this):

```
regasm.exe comdll.dll /tlb /nologo /codebase
```

Does anyone know which command Visual Studio 2010 uses to register COM dlls?

I have tried looking at the output window when building but this doesn't display anything.

When I use `regasm.exe` as described above, I get a message that the types are registered but no other messages. Shouldn't I get more information here?

Your help is much appreciated. If this is a duplicate please tell me. I have searched on stackoverflow but so far nothing has helped.

Comment: It is the correct command, assuming you used the correct version of regasm.exe (there are 4).  You also appear to get no complains from regasm.exe.  What you *completely* forgot is documenting what goes wrong.

Comment: What goes wrong is that the tool which implements my com object does not display it. Out of pure despair I have done a hard reset on my system and now it works. Should listen more to the 'IT crowd' guys. Have you turned it off and on again... Will accept smartis' answer for references in comments. Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no... (The Less You Know, the Better)

It put just this simple Line out. But it works. I use regasm.exe to implement my COM-ActiveX Controls.

If you want more Information you have to use OleView.exe, it's shows you a great Overview about the OLE and Interfaces at COM.

Comment: can you please give some more information. Perhaps links or code pieces I can use. I would like to know more about c# com programming but cant seem to find anything useful...

Comment: I know this was a hard piece of Research. - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712(v=vs.71).aspx - http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/programmatically-register-com-dlls-in-c/ - http://www.olavaukan.com/2010/08/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/